# Convert from Canvas coordinates to In world coordinates

Tags: unity-game-engine, coordinates

Every time the mouse is pressed, i log it's coordinates. What i need is a cube instantiated at the exact place the mouse was clicked.

I've looked through form posts and what i get is either answers witch are outdated or code that is really unreadable and messy. I tried using `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint` with a `Vector3` but the coordinates are always the same as the camera.
Here is the line of code:

```cs
Instantiate(prefab, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x,  Input.mousePosition.y, 0)), Quaternion.identity);
```

How do i convert from canvas coordinates to in world ones?

Comment: have you tried to use `10` instead of `0` for the `z` component of the vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the opposite function:

```
Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Vector3 position);
```

> position: A screen space position (often mouse x, y), plus a z
> position for depth (for example, a camera clipping plane).

Comment: Thank you but all the instances are at the camera's coordinates

Comment: @Nobert so why `0`? If your camera is at `-10` then in order to set it to `0` in the world you'ld need it `10` in front of the camera, right? ;)